# Scale to original size on mouseout using CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm using the keyframes to create an infinite scale up and scale down of a div on mouseover.
As you can see from the link below the parent box increase its sizes and then the child div start to scale up and down.
I would like that on mouse out, before the parent div will scale down, the child div return to its regular sizes in a smooth way.
Now, as you can see, it return to the original sizes suddenly, without any smoothness.

My keyframes:

```
@keyframes imageZoom {
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
    50% { transform: scale(1.24); }
    100% { transform: scale(1);}
}

@-moz-keyframes imageZoom {
    0% { -moz-transform: scale(1);}
    50% { -moz-transform: scale(1.24); }
    100% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageZoom {
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    50% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.24); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageZoom {
    0% { -ms-transform: scale(1); }
    50% { -ms-transform: scale(1.24); }
    100% { -ms-transform: scale(1); }
}
```

The child div styles:

```
#myFeaturedItems:hover article {
    animation: imageZoom linear 50s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation: imageZoom linear 50s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

#myFeaturedItems article {
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447688812233-3dbfff862778?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=01b98cd0603404826ec5df6d9ef46dfc');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

My demo link: http://emanuelezenoni.com/dev/test/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an `animation` to achieve what you want. A `transition` when you hover over the `article` is suitable. See my very basic example of the transition here below.

What it does:

```
transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
```

This will put a transition on the property `transform` for `1s` with easing `ease-in-out`. When you hover over `.box`, the `transform: scale(1.25);` will run, because we said that a transition was applied on it. The `overflow: hidden;` makes sure that the content will not be bigger than the box it's in.

You can tweak with the settings to your needs.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  margin-left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <article class="box">

  </article>

</div>
```